# What is the conventional way to input n^x?

Tags: mathematics

If I have a length or angle and type `=`, blender enters math mode where I can type equations to set the input of a transformation.

The only option I found is a very tedious $exp((1/2) * log(2))$ which there should be no reason to have to type. Can I not enter a simple radical instead?

Comment: I usually type sqrt(144) on my calculator instead of 144^(1/2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blender uses Python as its script language, so you write the exponent like this:

```
2**(1/2)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Found another...**

> The only option I found is a very tedious "exp((1/2)*log(2))" which
>   there should be no reason to have to type.

```
sqrt(2)
```

There is also the power method,

```
pow(2, 0.5)
```

Comment: Isn't that what we type on calculators too? \s

Comment: @10Replies also true.

Answer (score 3):

Blender uses Python for scripts and is therefore subject to Python's syntax.

The `^` operator or caret operator in python (as well as many other languages) represents the bitwise XOR operation.
You can find out more here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451386/what-does-the-caret-operator-in-python-do

If you want to know why programming languages feature `^` for XOR instead of exponents read here:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/331388/why-was-the-caret-used-for-xor-instead-of-exponentiation

You want to use `**` which is the exponent operator in Python